# libz.dylib libsqlite3.dylib not within Xcode 7, Parse not saving data

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift, parse-platform, xcode7

I am trying to work with Parse on an App, I am new to swift. But I downloaded Xcode 7 and it seems libz.dylib libsqlite3.dylib are missing and when I compile and build it is done successfully yet Parse does not show any data save. I tried adding -lz and -lsqlite3 onto "Other Linker Flags" yet that was not able to solve the issue. Anyone know how to add these libraries in?

Comment: Both of these libraries are OS built-ins, so I don't believe you're getting to the real source of the problem. You should be referencing the libraries in the 'Linked Frameworks and Libraries' section of the General project properties

Comment: I attempted to add them in the "Link Binary with Libraries" but they do not come up and the 'Linked Frameworks and Libraries' section but only "libsqlite3.tbd" comes up but neither of the two Parse directs me to add.

Comment: The `.tbd` is a new thing for XCode 7. They *should* link in the same manner as a `.dylib` would have on XCode 6.

Comment: oh thank you so for libz.dylib it would be libz.tbd?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: must be something else wrong since nothing saves in parse

Answer (score 22):

1. Go to Build Phases > Link Binary with Librairies > + > Add other...
2. Once in the file selection window do "CMD"+Shift+G (Go to folder) and type `/usr/lib/`. From `/usr/lib/` you can add `libz.dylib` and `libsqlite3.dylib`.

https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/9176#9176

Comment: Thanks, You saved my day!

Comment: These steps don't work on Xcode 7.2 on Mac OS X 10.11.3 - `libsqlite3.dylib` is nowhere to be found, even in `/usr/lib/`.

Comment: Thanks it's worked for me on Xcode7.2  on Mac OS X 10.11.1